# (Laravel) Missing required parameter for middleware route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> Error: Missing required parameters for [Route: auth.users.edit] [URI:
>   auth/users/{user}/edit].

I have a middleware, where if the user is missing some details, they will be taken to the edit account page and told to complete their account.

The middleware looks like this.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if ( // some condition about account completeness ) {

        flash('Please complete your account');
        return redirect()->route('auth.users.edit');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

the route name `auth.users.edit` corresponds to the route `auth/users/{user}/edit`. I am assuming the error I am getting is complaining that the middleware does not know the `{user}` paramater.

The error looks like this:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: auth.users.edit] [URI:
>   auth/users/{user}/edit]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, linuxartisan's answer was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right when you say

> I am assuming the error I am getting is complaining that the
>   middleware does not know the {user} paramater.

You should try this

```
return redirect()->route('auth.users.edit', [$user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just running

```
valet restart
```

and it worked.